# Get the user agent string of the user from a PHP file used to retrieve a CSS

Tags: php, html, css, user-agent

In an HTML page I have the following:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='retrievedCSS.php' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Inside `retrievedCSS.php`, I request a CSS resource from a CDN and I return it to the client.

Problem is CDN is quite "dynamic", so that if I directly execute `retrievedCSS.php` using the address bar of a browser, I get a different resource based on its `user-agent` string.

However, in my case, **it's the server requesting the resource to the CDN**, not a client.

Apart from appending it as a parameter (`retrievedCSS.php?ua=myUserAgent`) from the HTML page, is there any other way I can get the user agent string of the user loading the HTML page in `retrievedCSS.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're accessing a web page, your browser is adding the `User-Agent` to the request HTTP headers. As the CSS file is only another resource requested via HTTP, you should be able to access to header within the PHP file via:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

You can read about it [in the PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

EDIT: That should even work for your dynamic CSS file, as the browser is adding the header to all of the HTTP requests.

Comment: I suppose I can do it when the file is called directly from the address bar, or am I wrong?

Comment: Comment after the EDIT: ok, I'll give it a try   :-)

Comment: Should also work within your CSS file. If you like, you can open the Web Inspector (Chrome, Safari or Firefox), reload the page and you should see the header in the request of the CSS file.

Comment: There's no real CSS file: it's text generated from a remote server. PHP retrieves this text and returns it to the "root" HTML as text/css.

Comment: I know but the header is added anyway as you can see in the example of requesting SO: http://cloud.confirm.ch/qmeV

Answer (score 0):

You can access the user agent string using the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Comment: I suppose I can do it when the file is called directly from the address bar, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function. But it requires [browscap](http://php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.browscap).